# writing with variables in select statement does not work?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok here is my code:

```
<?php 
$cat1 = $_GET["cat1"];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT cat2 FROM products WHERE cat1 = $cat1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
die("Geen data beschikbaar");
}
while($category2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<a href=\"#\">".$category2["cat2"]."</a><br />";
}
?>
```

my url is http://www.websitename.com/category.php?cat1=Holland

Obviously this does not work altought i dont understand why. If I remove the variable after WHERE in the statement and just fill in 'Holland' it works great. So I am doing something not right with the syntax ? Thanks

Comment: If it's a string you must write : "SELECT DISTINCT cat2 FROM products WHERE cat1 = \'$cat1\'";

Comment: `echo $query`, spot the syntax error. BTW, you're wide open to SQL injection!

Comment: ...or `'$cat1'` or `'".$cat1."'`

Comment: [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) function can be useful if you want to debug your code and see what is wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- '".$cat1."' that worked. Also I know I am wide open to sql injection, but that is for later, when it all functions I will take care of that.

Comment: @BasSchreuder Great, glad to hear it, *cheers*

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: BTW, if you'd use parameterised queries with bound parameters (for SQL injection prevention), you wouldn't be having this problem in the first place. Don't leave stuff like this "for later", do it right from the beginning. It avoids many problems, now and later.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cat2"
    . " FROM products"
    . " WHERE cat1 = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $cat1) . "'";
```

Add single quotes around your string, and escape it to avoid sql injection.

Comment: I am new here, so I don't understand this -1 at my question..Someone dislikes or something?

Comment: Don't know who donvoted you, but i think, this happens because of the sql injection.

Comment: That really should be a placeholder, not a massively ugly inline escaping call, but points for patching that hole.